# Regex to check Illegal Search Pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, pattern-matching

I am trying to convert below function to a simple regex check to find illegal pattern in my search app.

The rules are

1. Any string without * :Not match.
2. * by itself :Not match.
3. if * is present and length of the string is less than 3 (ignoring space):Match

Here is what makes it tricky, | and (space)or(space) in my app results in running two different searches so therefore it has to evaluate the strings on each side separately. just like below function. the function works but the regexCheck doesn't.

```js
var regexCheck = /^[A-Za-z0-9]*$/g;

var check = function (s) {
    var flag = true;
  
    var b = s.replace(/ or /g,'|').split('|');
    for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        if (flag && b[i].indexOf('*') > - 1) {
            var startCount = (b[i].match(/[*]/g) || []).length;
            var limit = (startCount > 0) ? 2 : 3;
            var c = b[i].replace(/[ *]/g, '');
            if (c.length < limit && c.length > 0) {
                flag = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (flag) {
        console.log('good:' + s);
    } else {
        console.log('fail:' + s);
    }
    return flag;
};

var s = [
  'a',
  '*',
  'a*',
  '*a',
  'a*a',
  'a*a|aa',
  'a*a|a',
  'a*a|a*',
  'a*a or a*',
];
  
  
var j = 0;
while (j < s.length) {
    check(s[j]);
    if(regexCheck.test(s[j])){
        console.log('rg-good:' + s[j]);
    } else {
        console.log('rg-fail:' + s[j]);
    }
    j++;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I am too lazy to read your code and your explanation wasn't incredibly clear either. If I got you correctly, after you get a string and ignore all spaces: a match is either two character, one of which is a star, the other one is not, or two correct, matches separated by `|` or ` or `?

Comment: Yeah,I know, I apologize! This has been a confusing for me too. Yes, you got it right with the exception that the star only counts one time. so something like \*a\* is still illegal and has to match.

Comment: Final clarification - does the following match: `x*|xx`

Comment: Yes, simply saying, it has to evaluate each side of `|` separately, so it would be the `x*` that matches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, still not sure if I got you correctly, so please test and tell me if that is what you want:

```
/^.*(?:^| or |\|)(?=.?\*)(\**)[^\s\*](\**)(?=$| or |\|).*$/
```

Here is the version that ignores whitespaces:

```
/^.*(?:^| or |\|)\s*(?=\s*.?\s*\*)\s*(\*\s*)*[^\s\*]\s*(\*\s*)*(?=$| or |\|).*$/
```

To make it easier to understand, I will explain the basic one:

- Surround everything with `^.*` and `.*$` - this will make us match the entire string if one match is found. Aka if we have `a*|aa`, we will match the whole thing, not just `a*`. If you want to match only the subpattern - you can remove those.
- Surround everything with `(?:^| or |\|)` and `(?=$| or |\|)` -  will make us evaluate subpatterns one at a time. Aka separate each attempt to match with either line start/end, or `|`, or `or`.
- `(?=.?\*)` - positive lookahead that says "in the following pattern, either the first or the second character has to be a `*`. By the 3rd rule, the first found star shouldn't be at third or later position, nor are we allowed not to have a star by the 1st rule.
- `(\**)[^\s\*](\**)` - match any amount of `*`, followed by a character, that is not a star or a whitespace, followed by any amount of `*`.